# javac cannot found, even after adding non-standart path to it in $PATH

Tags: 12.10, bash, ntfs, environment-variables, paths

Ubuntu 12.10, 32bit
Problem too damn simple:
I have a NTFS partition and unpacked from .tar.gz jdk on it. All I need from bash, is to see javac compiler, that is located in directory `/media/mallniya/data/jdk1.7.0_25/bin`.
As it advised, I add the path to the javac in $PATH like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/media/mallniya/data/jdk1.7.0_25/bin
```

output of `$echo $PATH`:
`/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/media/mallniya/data/jdk1.7.0_25/bin`
And then I try to found or execute javac AND HAVE NOTHING:
output of `which javac` gives just nothing;
output of `ls -l` in the /media/$USERNAME/home/mallniya/jdk1.7.0_25/bin (without other files):

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5897 Jun  6 06:13 javac
```

output of `javac Example.java` (Example.java do exist, permission is ok):

```
bash: /media/mallniya/data/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javac: Permission denied
```

output of `sudo javac Example.java`:

```
sudo: javac: command not found
```

If the same directory jdk1.7.0_25/bin located on the other partition (ext4, for example), the problem is disappear.

I've found no restrictions about adding path in environment variable $PATH, but, obviously, for whatever reason it doesn't work with paths of NTFS partition.

Question: is it possible to add NTFS paths in the $PATH? I understand, that I can use the other path to add in the $PATH, but for now I want jdk to stay where it is.
Thank you.

Output of `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1003380k,nr_inodes=216328,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=202320k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/027924f8-ab47-4304-ab4d-f0586a6734bb / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755 0 0<br>
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/mallniya/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0<br>
/dev/sr0 /media/mallniya/GRMCULF(X)REO_EN-RU_DVD udf ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 0 0<br>
/dev/sda3 /media/mallniya/data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide the output of `cat /proc/mounts`. This will list the mounts and mount options. I suspect `noexec` is added as an option to your drive at `/media`, which will not allow to run applications from that medium. I can provide an answer if that's the case. Provide the information by **editing** your question.

Comment: Do you really need to install the JDK from upstream tar file? The Oracle Java JDK is available in a PPA: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

Comment: On a side note, use `type` rather than `which` to see what/where the command is. `type javac`, or `type -a javac` to also see other javac commands available.

Comment: @gertvdijk, thank you for rapid response and I'm so sorry about my slow reaction :( The output of `cat /proc/mounts` now in the question. And yeah - it's better to use PPA. @geriha: your method actually works and javac dispays in the output of `type javac`.

Comment: And a little surprise for me: it's eventually worked, when I had changed `/etc/fstab` like this:<br>

    `UUID=7A0063220062E49B /media/mallniya/data ntfs 0 0`
remount and try `which` again. All is ok. And the other important thing: to the output of `cat /proc/mounts` in the line `/dev/sda3 /media/mallniya/data` was added only string `default_permissions`. I'm pretty sure, that's the problem was with mount options.